# Conditional return in function python

Tags: python, function

I want to establish an function to return its party based on hashtag. Here is what I got:

```
def party(tw) #define party by compare hashtag to a predefined list
    #extract hashtag words from tw, and store them in tag_dict
    tag_dict={tag.strip("#") for tag in tw.split() if tag.startswith("#")} 
    tag in tag_dict

    #Compare each hashtag with Party Number of each hash tag, assign and party number to each hashtag
    party_number={k:int(party_tag[k]) for k in tag_dict if k in party_tag}

    #extract the value of party number to a variable: number
    number = party_number.values()

    if number==1
        return "Liberal"
    if number==2
        return "Conservative"
    if number==3
        return "NPD"
    if number==0
        return "Other"
```

How can I write the conditional return? And how can I handle when a tweet has several party's hashtag?

Comment: `number` is not a number but a list of numbers (a view of dictionary values). What is the function supposed to return? A list of party names?

Answer (score 0):

If it is always going to be an integer you can build a list and return the appropriate value based on that list. Such as:

```
from random import randint

def return_something():
  parties = ["Other", "Liberal", "Conservative", "NPD"]
  number = randint(0,3)
  print(number)
  try: #return number if exist (could change "not found" to "Other"
    return parties[number]
  except IndexError: #I.E. not in the list
    return "Party not found."

print(return_something())
```

---

If it has string values you could use a dictionary instead, such as this sample code:

```
parties = {'dem': "Liberal", 'rep': "Conservative", 'market': "NPD"}
#Defining the dictionary out of the function so it doesn't have to be rebuilt

def return_something(p):
  return parties.get(p, 'Other') #fetches and returns a value or a default ("Other")

party = "not in tag" #or whatever you use to get values
print(return_something(party))
```

---

or alternatively:

```
def return_something(p):
    return {
        'dem': "Liberal", 
        'rep': "Conservative", 
        'market': "NPD"
    }.get(p, "Other")

print(return_something("market"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed the data type, so it can return a string directly.